# Convert python string into integer without commas in them

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup4 to extract prices tag from a website. The code i m using is this

```
 #price
        try:
            price = soup.find('span',{'id':'actualprice'})
            price_result= str(price.get_text())
            print "Price: ",price_result
        except StandardError as e:
            price_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
            print price_result
```

The output i m getting is a string with a format with commas in it. e.g.
`82,000,00`

**What i want:**

Change the format from string price to integer price without commas in it so that i can use them as values intead of strings in excel

Comment: What do you mean by "without commas"? You want to remove commas from your number, or simple change it into dot?

Comment: All i want is to use it as a number when i extract it so i can do  my computation.

Comment: netter to have it without commas

Comment: It's a weird notation. Normally it would be 82,000.00 or 82.000,00. Are the "numbers" always like this format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
>>> string = '82,000,00'
>>> int(price_result.replace(',', ''))
8200000
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make it 100 times bigger?

Comment: It depends whether the second comma separates the fractional part or not. The question is not clear about this...

Comment: there is no point. this solves

Comment: If I use the method above, I am getting this ```invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html or https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html depending on the Python version you are using and use the "replace()" function:

```
int_price = int(price_result.replace(',',''))
```

This replaces all commas within the string and then casts it to an INT:

```
>>> price = "1,000,000"
>>> type(price)
<type 'str'>
>>> int_price = int(price.replace(',',''))
>>> type(int_price)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the last part is a fractional part, you could do something like this:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'((?:\d{1,3},?)+)(,\d{2})')
m = r.match('82,000,00')
v = m.group(1).replace(',', '') + m.group(2).replace(',', '.')
print(float(v))
```

Output:

```
82000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', '82,000,00'))
```

or another method will be,

```
int(filter(str.isdigit, '82,000,00'))
```